# Removing duplicates while reading multiple text files using Python

Tags: python, parsing, data-cleaning

I am trying to:

- read multiple text files
- keep only header of first file
- account for formatting issues (e.g. special characters)
- merge them into one file

This is the code, I came up with:

```
import glob

read_files = glob.glob(data_path + "*.txt")

header_saved = False
with open(data_path +"result.txt","w") as outfile:
    for f in read_files:
        with open(f) as infile:
            header = next(infile)
            if not header_saved:
                outfile.write(header)
                header_saved = True
            text = infile.read()
            replaced_text = re.sub(r"[-()\"#@;:<>{}`+=~|.!?,]", "", text)
            outfile.write(replaced_text+"\n")
```

The problem is, for some reason this produces duplicated rows.

Does someone see the code parts which are at fault?

I appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: When you step through your code line-by-line in a debugger, which line is the duplication happening on? Is it already duplicated in `replaced_text`?

Comment: yep I'd add debug prints to all the steps to see what is read and written when